# "// TODO sg: TMP solution until we are confident..." showing up on question pages on multiple sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I'm seeing

> "// TODO sg: TMP solution until we are confident in our current
> implementation of async imports // once we are, we can move the if
> into the js entry file and dynamically load the mark obsolete module"

at the bottom of each page (directly above the footer) on all question pages,  I have tried multiple browsers.

Seems to be in this snippet:

```
<script>StackExchange.ready(function(){$.get('/posts/375317/ivc/cf81');});</script>
<noscript><div><img src="/posts/375317/ivc/cf81" class="dno" alt="" width="0" height="0"></div></noscript><div style="display:none" id="js-codeblock-lang"></div></div>

                        
// TODO sg: TMP solution until we are confident in our current implementation of async imports
// once we are, we can move the if into the js entry file and dynamically load the mark obsolete module

        </div>
    </div>

            <footer id="footer" class="site-footer js-footer" role="contentinfo">
```

Just load any question and scroll down to replicate the issue.

Comment: Yep, repro here Brave 64 up-to-date, no addons, windows 10. Ditto Chrome 64 up-to-date.

Comment: someone forgot to properly format their comment in the code...

Comment: well, it clearly says this a *temporary* solution, nothing to see here :)

Comment: Don't worry they kept TODO in the code so they won't forget to change it later.

Comment: Can confirm, this appears on all sites

Comment: Reproduced, although it only appears on questions where I already have an answer.

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [Is this "TODO" supposed to be at the bottom of the page?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415411/4642212).

Comment: Someone will be wearing the hat today! https://www.zazzle.com/i_broke_the_build_hat-148784039664477752

Comment: I love this TODO. Please don't remove it. FYI: [Hofstadter's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_law): "It always takes longer than you expect, even when you take into account Hofstadter's Law."

Comment: Should replace it with "//todo: remove todo"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is part of our new tradition here at Stack Overflow... Whoops Wednesday.

Thanks for the report! The fix is out now.

Comment: Please keep this tradition up! 

Comment: Excited to see what's in store for next week 

Comment: Remarkably, they are now doing it on Mondays too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387507/todo-remove-after-april-fools-2023-is-done