# Who is Samuel Ordonez and why are they a moderator here?

Tags: support, bug, moderators, security, hacked

I just noticed [this profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1101280/samuel-ordonez):

[image: moderator who should not be moderator]

What is going on?

If it's a new SE staff member, shouldn't they only get staff bit, and not moderator?

Or is this a new hacker?

There are more cases like this on other sites as well, e.g. [this one on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17542301/user17542301):

[image: 1 rep user moderator on Stack Overflow]

And most likely more cases all across Stack Exchange.

Comment: They seem to be a long-standing not very active community member on SO, so I wonder what's going on here too...

Comment: @Oleg simple... either a bug on SE side, or a very bold hacker. :)

Comment: Seems like they weren't joking about the whoopsie wednesday then... :)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine what happened in Wednesday?

Comment: @Exampleperson First mentioned here: ["// TODO sg: TMP solution until we are confident..." showing up on question pages on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375324/289905). Today, also referenced here: [Cannot edit answer from review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416472/4642212#comment898629_416472).

Comment: @Exampleperson it's kind of a meme, joke, never meant to be serious.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron wow oh today is wednesday. I can't believe that look this long to realize

Comment: I wonder if we just need a more generic question asking SE to .... rationalise... their on and offboarding process

Comment: @JourneymanGeek don't think so, since we know exactly nothing about how it currently works, we can only guess.

Comment: We don't need to. We need them to make it clearer and less confusing, and make sure staff get the staff *and* diamond as needed,

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They are staff. Something obviously went wrong with onboarding or an account merge and left them listed as a mod, but without the staff label. This has been fixed (and we'll follow up internally to see how we can prevent this from happening in the future).

Thanks for your diligence.

> who is that new mod?
> if they're staff, why no label?
> oh. they are staff. fine.

Comment: Who is https://stackoverflow.com/users/17542301/user17542301, why is the mod label removed from them now?

Comment: That was an account that belonged to the same user in question before an account merge. Issues with the account merge are most likely the root of what went wrong here.

Answer (score 14):

According to [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/samuel-ordonez-lavine), Samuel Ordonez Lavine is a Platform Developer at Stack Overflow, since November 2021. It looks like the staff bit wasn't awarded properly, however.

Comment: Hope that's the case. Still, would love to have the bug fixed, it's really confusing to see random 1 rep users become moderators all of a sudden.

Comment: Confirmed, they are staff. I have them now properly marked as an employee (and need to figure out what went wrong here).