# "//Todo: Remove after April Fools 2023 is done"

Tags: bug, status-completed, april-fools

I noticed that it says "// TODO: Remove after April Fools 2023 is done" at the bottom of MSE... What're y'all up to? And could you be a *little* sneakier? Screenshot's off my phone cause it's smaller but it's there on desktop too.

[image: footer of Meta Stack Exchange page, showing "// TODO: Remove after April Fools 2023 is done" at the very bottom]

Comment: How do you know this isn't just the first easter egg in a long april fools themed treasure hunt? 

Comment: @KyleMit because if you were properly sneaky there would not actually be a treasure hunt, only tell people there was 

Comment: @KyleMit meh, it doesn't even blink.

Comment: Similar older bug (so perhaps a regression): ["// TODO sg: TMP solution until we are confident..." showing up on question pages on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375317/todo-sg-tmp-solution-until-we-are-confident-showing-up-on-question-page)

Comment: It's 2 weeks early to be part of an April Fools-themed anything that was intentional.

Comment: You really should have codenames for that kind of projects -- `// TODO - Remove after CivilInsecureUnicorn is done` would give out far less.

Comment: What *is* the unicorn insecure about?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The shame

We have some local tooling in the footer that hid this really obvious mistake during our testing. That's right, we've bamboozled ourselves!

Sorry about that, a fix is out now. Thank you for reporting!

Comment: Maybe add another step "View the front page and some random internal pages with bare eyes, without any fancy tools, before publishing?"

Comment: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14939/what-is-this-todo-message seems to have been reported on super user

Comment: this really makes me think we need a [meta-tag:status-oops] or something.

Comment: hmm. Its april first. I wonder if this *was* the april fool's day joke :D

Comment: I suppose it was :`(